# Why does this code return a java.net.socketException?

Tags: java, networking

these are my client and server class but i don't know that why the text received doesn't work in a correct way (it will return something but not the one that I want) also when I close the run part of server i will have these exceptions,please help me.thanks

server side:

```
final static Vector handlers = new Vector(10);
private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader in;
private PrintWriter out;

public ChatHandler(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    this.socket = socket;
    in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(
            new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true));
}

@Override
public void run() {
    String line;

    synchronized (handlers) {
        handlers.addElement(this);

    }
    try {

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && !line.equalsIgnoreCase("/quit")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < handlers.size(); i++) {
                synchronized (handlers) {
                    ChatHandler handler =
                            (ChatHandler) handlers.elementAt(i);
                    handler.out.println(line + "\r");
                    handler.out.flush();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            synchronized (handlers) {
                handlers.removeElement(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

client side: ( apart of that)

```
public static synchronized void active() {

    String teXt = MainClient.getText();

    os.println(teXt);
    os.flush();
    try {
        String line = is.readLine();



            setFromServertext("Text recieved:"+line+"\n");

        is.close();
        is.close();
        c.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

active method will be called when the user write something on the text area and click on the send button.

stacktrace:

```
    init:
deps-jar:
compile-single:
run-single:
Server is starting...
Server is listening...
Client Connected...
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
    at ServerNetwork.ChatHandler.run(ChatHandler.java:44)
Client Connected...
Client Connected...
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
    at ServerNetwork.ChatHandler.run(ChatHandler.java:44)
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 15 minutes 53 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when the socket is closed, which causes the connection to be aborted
The [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close()) of `close()` states:

> Any thread currently blocked in an I/O operation upon this socket will throw a `SocketException`.

Use `shutdownOutput()` if you want a TCP's normal connection termination.
If shutdownOutput is called at the server, the readLine() at the client will return null, indicating an EOF (end of file). Now the client should call shutdownOutput.